# the difference between mysql server and mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I've instaled MySQL workbench in Windows 7 64bit. Unfortunately, I'm facing problems:

In the Object Browser, when I click on my DB and right click on tables to create one, I can not insert any column (disabled) and therefore, can not insert tables. check this: 
[Can not create table in MySQL workbench 5.2.40](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245475/can-not-create-table-in-mysql-workbench-5-2-40)

I can create table from the EER model. But even though, I faced problems when tried to connect my Java application to this database.
[MySQL and Java: table doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244012/mysql-and-java-table-doesnt-exist)

I have searched, and not sure from this, some of what I found is that workbench have probelms with Windows 7 - 64 bit (any idea if this is correct??). The only version I found was for 68, it installed successfully but I'm having probems.

I want to downlod MySQL server but before that: Will Mysql Server give me the same features that the workbench does? I need to work with GUI (insert, delete, update,..etc).

**EDIT:**

Also, the table I added using the EER are not visible in the Object browser. I only can see the schema in the Object browser without any table underneath it.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right privileges to add tables to the DB?  Using Workbench 5.2.39 here on Win7 64 and I cannot reproduce the problem you're facing.

Comment: I'm using the root user. What elese can be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are for manipulate the structure, queries and function, procedure, etc....

In Both you can Use DML and DDL

If you ask me I love Server even if you can create really cool designs on workbench, but basically you can do the same in both (insert, delete, update,..etc and more)

So it's up to you, I think MySQL server is a little bit lighter that Workbench, but if you want to, try it both.

Workbench looks like more friendly

Comment: Most importantly, can it provide me with GUI?

Comment: Yes, if you double click tables it will make a "select * from table" and create everything with a nice GUI and everything is click-able

Comment: In terms of efficiency is there a difference, my query in workbench seems to take more than an hour.

Answer (score 17):

MySQL Workbench is a MySQL Server GUI. The two are different products. MySQL Workbench requires a MySQL Server connection for most tasks (except for data modeling). This reliance on a MySQL connection is clearer in the latest version of MySQL Workbench (6.1) than it was in 5.2.

Answer (score 8):

MySql Workbench and MySql Server both are completely different things. MySql Server is basically a database and MySql workbench is a GUI  or graphical management tool which helps us interact with MySql server database.

Similarly, SQL Server Management Studio is the graphical management tool for SQL Server.